# Xunit 2.3.0 Unable to pass dates as inline params

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

In xUnit 2.2 and prior versions, we were able to pass date strings as inline data when implementing a Theory.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("title 1", "testing 1", 1, "Educational", "2017-3-1", "2018-12-31")]
[InlineData("title 2", "testing 2", 2, "Self Employment", "2017-2-1", "2018-2-28")]
public async Task WhenPassingCorrectData_SuccessfullyCreate(
    string title,
    string description,
    int categoryId,
    string category,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate)
{

}
```

But with 2.3 update this seems to be broken and Visual studio is giving a compile error.

> The value is not convertible to the method parameter 'startDate' of
>   type 'System.DateTime

Has anyone got a workaround for this other that having to receive dates as strings and cast them inside the test method?

And would this be a temporary bug in this version and will be fixed in future version?

PS: I'm using xUnit on a .netcore project on VS2017

Comment: Was not aware it ever did that (what time zone and/or datetimekind would you like it to guess if it was going to  magically parse them anyway - what about if you wanted it to do `DateTimeOffset` ?). I'd suggest replacing it with a MemberData which `yield`s them as `DateTime`s

Comment: It was parsing to a Datetime with Kind as unspecific and it was good enough in most cases (at least in my current project). Its equivalent to constructing a datetime as, DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1). Yeah it wont help to get a DateTimeOffset. Could you please give an example of you the approach you mentioned?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The root problem here is that the `InlineDataAttribute` construction syntax is fiddly and has corner cases. Also, ultimately everything needs to be tunnelled through attributes. xUnit.NET has a variety of constructs that are more powerful than `InlineData`, that can be used instead of it, which will handle any type (for your case, the `DateTime`).

If you're OK with having to repeat yourself on the type names, [xUnit's built-in `TheoryData` is the best tool for lists of things that you want to use full C# syntax to define](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57789025/11635). The cleanest usage looks like this:

```cs
public static TheoryData<string, string, int, string, DateTime, DateTime> Cases =
    new()
    {
        { "title 1", "testing 1", 1, "Educational", new DateTime(2017, 3, 1), new DateTime(2018, 12, 31) },
        { "title 2", "testing 2", 2, "Self Employment", new DateTime(2017, 2, 1), new DateTime(2018, 2, 28) }
    };

[Theory, MemberData(nameof(Cases))]
public async Task WhenPassingCorrectData_SuccessfullyCreate(
    string title, 
    string description, 
    int categoryId, 
    string category, 
    DateTime startDate, 
    DateTime endDate)
{
}
```

See [this great post from Andrew Lock for a rundown on `TheoryData`](https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/). TL;DR there is a `.Add` on `TheoryData`, and the `new() {}` initialization expression will call `.Add` on it for each row you add.

---

With [C# 12 Collection Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions), it can be done like this, but there's less type checking *(but you also don't need to repeat the type names from the argument list)* :-

```cs
// NB C# 12 Collection Expressions - see below for backcompat version if not building with v8 SDK
public static readonly object[][] Cases =
[
    ["title 1", "testing 1", 1, "Educational", new DateTime(2017, 3, 1), new DateTime(2018, 12, 31)],
    ["title 2", "testing 2", 2, "Self Employment", new DateTime(2017, 2, 1), new DateTime(2018, 2, 28)]
];
```

(This leans on a long-standing xUnit feature - `MemberData` and friends ultimately feed everything through to the runner as an `object[]`.)

---

If you're not on the .NET 8 SDK, the best syntax for the `Cases` is sadly:

```cs
public static readonly object[][] Cases =
{
  new object[] { "title 1", "testing 1", 1, "Educational", 
                  new DateTime(2017,3,1), new DateTime(2018,12,31)},
  new object[] { "title 2", "testing 2", 2, "Self Employment", 
                  new DateTime(2017, 2, 1), new DateTime(2018, 2, 28)}
};
```

---

ASIDE: You can also make the property return `IEnumerable<object[]>`, which you'd typically do with [`yield return` enumerator syntax](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/), but I believe the above is the most legible syntax C# has to offer for it pre C# 12 / .NET 8.

---

Really ugly hack:

```
static TheoryData<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> MakeTheoryData<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(IEnumerable<(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)> values)
{
    var tmp = new TheoryData<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>();
    foreach(var (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6) in values)
        tmp.Add(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);
    return tmp;
}

public static TheoryData<string, string, int, string, DateTime, DateTime> Cases = MakeTheoryData(
    [
        ( "title 1", "testing 1", 1, "Educational", new DateTime(2017, 3, 1), new DateTime(2018, 12, 31) ),
        ( "title 2", "testing 2", 2, "Self Employment", new DateTime(2017, 2, 1), new DateTime(2018, 2, 28) )
    ]);
```

As of 2.6.6, `TheoryData` [has a constructor that can be used with collection constructors:](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2854), which lets you avoid having a `MakeTheoryData`:

```
public static TheoryData<string, string, int, string, DateTime, DateTime> Cases =
    [
        ( "title 1", "testing 1", 1, "Educational", new DateTime(2017, 3, 1), new DateTime(2018, 12, 31) ),
        ( "title 2", "testing 2", 2, "Self Employment", new DateTime(2017, 2, 1), new DateTime(2018, 2, 28) )
    ];
```

---

Finally, [for V3 a tuple collection syntax like the previous one, but without the `MakeTheoryData` helper comes out fo the box](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2836#issuecomment-1841542051)

Comment: That helped me..Thanks.

Comment: Getting an exception if I don't make CorrectData public. Please fix.

Comment: This is pretty horrible. It means that we can't use actual classes. We need to pass data in as a loose array.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper Can you expand? you can also pass classes - key thing is all inputs to an attribute need to be representable as some very basic types - the MemberData mechanism lets you pass either arrays of objects where the index maps to the parameter order, or you can pass a single class instance (and have the memberData yield an `object[]` where each array has a single item)

Comment: @RubenBartelink sure. Check out my answer. I wrote an article here: https://christianfindlay.com/2019/06/30/xunit-strongly-typed-test-data/

Comment: Thanks for expanding - yes, creating a class to encapsulate a set of inputs can sometimes make sense

Comment: @christianFindlay The TheoryData approach I just added is probably what you wanted back in the day, though with the Collection Expressions, you might be able to work out something in between

Comment: @wijitha Updated just now. Will remove this comment later - also feel free to remove your original one, I feel thanked enough! I think Christian's inputs should stay in the comment stream though...

Answer (score 20):

The better way to do it currently is to use TheoryData so that you can use strongly typed inputs. 
[Creating strongly typed xUnit theory test data with TheoryData](https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/)

```
TheoryData<DateTime> MemberData = new TheoryData<DateTime>
{
 DateTime.Now, 
 new DateTime(), 
 DateTime.Max
}
```

Comment: far as i can tell this is the correct answer, maybe the syntactic sugar of ClassData came later, but thanks much!

Comment: I'm downvoting because the link doesn't work anymore, I had to visit Google web cache to read the article. Your example doesn't show how to pass this `MemberData` to the Unit test

Comment: Upvoting, the link appears to be working. Very elegant solution.

Comment: The link [Creating strongly typed xUnit theory test data with TheoryData](https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/) is working - in case it does not one time here is a [link to the archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20221130045417/https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/)

Comment: Upvoted way back; Ultimately `TheoryData` is definitely worth using if it fits. NOTE I also stole this and incorporated it into my answer just now as I felt it is worth comparing and contrasting with Collection Expressions, which make the other approach slightly more palatable.

Answer (score 10):

It appears that this bug is fixed in v2.4.0+ (this feature stopped working in at least v2.3.1?)

If unable to upgrade xunit to a version with the fix then perhaps do the equivalent of what xunit is doing implicitly:

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/07457dab8d0bb188e74e476c062a4a9aeca44711/src/xunit.v3.common/Reflection/Reflector.cs#L88-L92

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("title 1", "testing 1", 1, "Educational", "2017-3-1", "2018-12-31")]
[InlineData("title 2", "testing 2", 2, "Self Employment", "2017-2-1", "2018-2-28")]
public async Task WhenPassingCorrectData_SuccessfullyCreate(
    string title,
    string description,
    int categoryId,
    string category,
    string startDate, // <-- change from `DateTime` to `string`
    string endDate)   // <-- change from `DateTime` to `string`
{
    var expectedStartDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate); // <-- add this
    var expectedEndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);     // <-- add this

    //  rest of test ...

}
```

Otherwise if have more complicated tests then perhaps use `MemberDataAttribute` as others suggested.

Comment: Thanks, and yes it's working!. I'm using xUnit v2.4.1 didn't know about the fix.

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good way to pass strongly typed test data in to xUnit Tests

[Blog Post](https://wordpress.com/post/christianfindlay.com/649)

[Source Code](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Samples/blob/6b69b4933143fe9b2e43385f3b5acb1b85724075/xUnit/Sample.Tests/Sample.Tests/UnitTest1.cs#L6)

```
public class SampleData
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C => A + B;
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The test data must have this return type and should be static
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData
    {
        get
        {
            //Load the sample data from some source like JSON or CSV here.
            var sampleDataList = new List<SampleData>
            {
                new SampleData { A = 1, B = 2 },
                new SampleData { A = 3, B = 2 },
                new SampleData { A = 2, B = 2 },
                new SampleData { A = 3, B = 23 },
                new SampleData { A = 43, B = 2 },
                new SampleData { A = 3, B = 22 },
                new SampleData { A = 8, B = 2 },
                new SampleData { A = 7, B = 25 },
                new SampleData { A = 6, B = 27 },
                new SampleData { A = 5, B = 2 }
         };

            var retVal = new List<object[]>();
            foreach(var sampleData in sampleDataList)
            {
                //Add the strongly typed data to an array of objects with one element. This is what xUnit expects.
                retVal.Add(new object[] { sampleData });
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }

/* Alternate form

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData() 
    {
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 1, B = 2 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 3, B = 2 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 2, B = 2 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 3, B = 23 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 43, B = 2 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 3, B = 22 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 8, B = 2 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 7, B = 25 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 6, B = 27 } };
        yield return new [] { new SampleData { A = 5, B = 2 } };
    }
*/

/* Or:

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData() =>
        from x in new[] { 
            new SampleData { A = 1, B = 2 },
            new SampleData { A = 3, B = 2 },
            new SampleData { A = 2, B = 2 },
            new SampleData { A = 3, B = 23 },
            new SampleData { A = 43, B = 2 },
            new SampleData { A = 3, B = 22 },
            new SampleData { A = 8, B = 2 },
            new SampleData { A = 7, B = 25 },
            new SampleData { A = 6, B = 27 },
            new SampleData { A = 5, B = 2 } }
        select new object[] { x};
    */

    /// <summary>
    /// Specify the test data property with an attribute. This method will get executed 
    /// for each SampleData object in the list
    /// </summary>
    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(TestData))]       
    public void Test1(SampleData sampleData)
    {
        Assert.Equal(sampleData.A + sampleData.B, sampleData.C);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code above isn't meant to represent the actual code you'd end up with. It's broken in to two steps because you'd want to deserialize the data, or load the data through some other means in to a strongly typed list. The second part with the foreach loop is the part which converts the loaded data in to the format that xUnit expects. This is lost in alternate version which is not what I posted. But, this alternate form is fair enough if you are building the test data in to the class.

Comment: Another way could be: new List<object[]>(sampleDataList.Select(t => new object[] { t }));