# DateTime used as InlineData in xUnit Theory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes, xunit

I have a simple problem wherein I want to use a `DateTime` as a variable in my test cases.

I'm using it like this:

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(Constants.valid_string, Constants.valid_string, DateTime.Now)] //DateTime.Now is producing an error
    public void MappingSuccessAppIDTest(
        string? appID,
        string? shortID,
        DateTime? date
    )
    {
        //Arrange
        ApplicationID modelName = new()
        {
            application_id = appID,
            short_id = shortID,
            created_date = date,
        };
        //Act
        ApplicationIDValidator validator = new();
        FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult result = validator.TestValidate(modelName);
        //Assert
        Assert.True(result.IsValid);
    }
```

However I'm receiving this Compiler Error:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

But I can't do this for a workaround:

```
public const string valid_date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

since `DateTime` is not a native type in the C# language, and `const` can only be created on native types.

How do I add my `date` in the `inlineData`?

Comment: If `DateTime.Now` is going to be constant for all of your tests, then remove it from `InlineData` and just call it in your test. If you need to have different dates, then pass in a string/long(ticks) and then parse it in the code.

Comment: DateTime.now is just an example, I will add invalid dates later. But I've thought about using strings then parsing it as well, but I don't know if that's the simplest most straightforward solution

Comment: If DateTime.Now is just an example and you're not going to use it, why would you care if that doesn't work then?

Comment: Some cases for example I will add DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), and this will assert fail. but the type is still a DateTime so it's not going to be valid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828374/xunit-2-3-0-unable-to-pass-dates-as-inline-params

Comment: By the way, `DateTime` is as much a native type as `Int32` (aka `int`). The restriction is that arguments to Attribute constructors must be literals or `const` (or a few added things like `Type`s or arrays of literals or consts), just like the error says. You can use integer ticks or (for readability) strings you can parse.

Comment: You can also use ClassData or MethodData instead of InlineData

Comment: Yeah, I think either ClassData or MethodData is the answer I'm looking for most. Thanks @Hayden

Comment: @Hayden, I asked a new question here you might be able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578405/testdata-does-not-implement-interface-member-ienumerable-getenumerator

Answer (score 0):

Now is a bad choice for unit tests, since it will change every time you run the test.  See [this](https://ayende.com/blog/3408/dealing-with-time-in-tests) for a discussion on handling time in unit tests.  But assuming you have a fixed time you want to test

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(Constants.valid_string, Constants.valid_string, "2023-02-01T12:23:34Z")] 
public void MappingSuccessAppIDTest(
    string? appID,
    string? shortID,
    sting? dateString
)
{
    //Arrange
    ApplicationID modelName = new()
    {
        application_id = appID,
        short_id = shortID,
        created_date = DateTime.Parse(dateString),
    };
    //Act
    ApplicationIDValidator validator = new();
    FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult result = validator.TestValidate(modelName);
    //Assert
    Assert.True(result.IsValid);
}
```