# 'TestData' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit

I'm following a tutorial to write [XUnit ClassData Attribute](https://beetechnical.com/tech-tutorial/xunit-theory-memberdata-inlinedata/#:%7E:text=XUnit%20ClassData%20Attribute). It shows the following code:

```
public class EmployeeTestData:IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { new Employee { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "" } };
        yield return new object[] { new Employee { Id = 2, FirstName = "Mary", LastName = null } };
        yield return new object[] { new Employee { Id = 3, FirstName = "Mary", LastName = null } };
        yield return new object[] { new Employee { Id = 4, FirstName = "", LastName = null } };
        yield return new object[] { new Employee { Id = 5, FirstName = "", LastName = "john" } };
        yield return new object[] { new Employee { Id = 6, FirstName = null, LastName = " " } };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

above is an example of creating a `classData` for the tests used in `XUnit` `theory`.

When I try to recreate it on my test `classData`, it produces an error even though I haven't changed much in the code.

```
public class ApplicationTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { new RAFApplication { id = "1", AppID = 1, short_id = "1" } };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?

Comment: Define the `using System.Collections` namespace at the top

Comment: The reason you will need to do this is likely because you have implicit usings enabled, which might be trying to resolve the `System.Collections.Generic` IEnumerable/IEnumerator.

Comment: Ah that was embarrassing. I was relying on the show potential fixes on VS and it didn't show that option. Thanks again

Comment: Always look at all the error messages as well - the `IEnumerator IEnumerable` part is underlined in red, and I strongly suspect there was an error message saying something like "The type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` cannot be used without type arguments."

Comment: @JonSkeet is there any reason why the using System.Collections is not being suggested by VS? the IEnumerator IEnumerable is solved by importing System.Collections as well, which I wouldn't have figured out since in my mind there's an entirely different cause of the error.

Comment: @ProsyArceno: I don't think you should expect VS to be able to fix every possible problem. Sooner or later, you're going to have to *know* that there are two different types, one generic and one non-generic. That's why I highlighted the error about not using type arguments - because that should have been a lightbulb moment where you'd say "Ah, but for that member I didn't mean the generic type, I meant the non-generic type" - leading to "How would the compiler know about the non-generic type?" leading to "Ah, I'm missing a using directive."