# How to set priority for InlineData() from Xunit Theory test

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

I have following test

```
[Theory(DisplayName = nameof(GenerativeAnswersResponseAsync))]
[InlineData("GenerativeAnswers1", GenerativeAnswers_InDomainTest, false, true)]
[InlineData("GenerativeAnswers2", GenerativeAnswers_OutDomainTest, false, true)]
```

How can I set priority so that "GenerativeAnswers1" is executed first?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes such as `InlineData` on a method don't have a guaranteed relative order, so they'll arrive from the reflection APIs in the order the compiler fed them into the assembly.

If you want to control the order, you'll have to do that via [`MemberData`, `ClassData`](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) or [`TheoryData`](https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/)

Comment: Could you please give any example? Thanks

Comment: Maybe some of the stuff in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828374/xunit-2-3-0-unable-to-pass-dates-as-inline-params/47835325#47835325 might be useful but tbh you're best off working through the two linked articles